# generate random number through multiple iterations

Tags: python, random, iteration

I need to generate a random number over several iterations, which can only 'swing' with +/- 20 after each iteration (except for the first one). Let me try and explain.

1. Iteration generates a random number from range(1, 100))

IF I choose two iterations then:

2. iteration generates a random number, where the value is limited to be +/- 20 of the result of 1. iteration. -still within 1-100.

And IF I choose three iterations then:

3. iteration generates a random number, where the value is limited to be +/- 20 of the result of 2. iteration. -still within 1-100.

and so on.

This here was the best I was able to come up with at the given time.

```
item1 = range(1, 100)

item2 = range(301, 400)
item22 = range(301, 349)
item222 = range(350, 400)


search_word = raw_input("\nENTER DAYS: ")

if search_word == "1":
    print(random.choice(item1))

if search_word == "2":
    if (random.choice(item2)) > 350:
        print (random.choice(item22))
    else:
        print (random.choice(item222))
```

Comment: What code did you try, and what were the problems with it?

Comment: I retrospect: What would be needed is to store the result of iteration 1 in a variable, and then make the following iterations at random number in the range of fortyone numbers with the result of the previous iteration in the middle. And so on.

I dont write Python anymore so I am not exactly sure who the code would work.

Answer (score 1):

The question is not clear, if I have it wrong, please clarify.
Try:

```
N[0] = random(1,100)
for i in range(1, iterations)
    N[i] = random( max(N[i-1]-20,1),  min(N[i-1]+20, 100) )
```

This constrains the following numbers to +-20 and min=1, max=100
It also ensures in each iterations the numbers are equally likely